# If a pointer variable has the same address as its value, is it really pointing to itself?

Tags: c, pointers

For example - in the following piece of code, is a a pointer to itself?

```
#include<stdio.h>  
int main(){    
    int* a;    
    int b = (int)&a;    
    a = b;    
    printf("address of a = %d\n", &a);    
    printf("  value of a = %d\n", a); 
}
```

If a is not a pointer to itself, then the same question poses again: Can a pointer point to itself? Also, how is a self pointing pointer useful?

Comment: The example makes more sense if a is of type `void *`.  An int * points to an int (not an int *), but a void * can point to a void *.

Comment: Hmm, strange how this is the exact same code (including the same bug) as in the duplicate. Reposting for karma?

Comment: "Possible" duplicate ?  If this isn't a duplicate - cut, dried, lock it up and throw away the key - then I don't know what is!  The wording is verbatim, right down to the punctuation and code example!  I have to say also that it smells strongly (reeks) of a homework assignment.

Comment: Well, I downvoted this and the original.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ill-formed, your compiler should give an error.  `a = b;` fails: `int` is not implicitly convertible to `int *`.

Supposing you fix it to say:

```
int *a = (int *)&a;
```

then it could be said that `a` points at the same byte in memory where `a` itself is stored.  However it would cause undefined behaviour to read or write through `*a` (strict aliasing violation).